# App runs well at all versions of iphone but on iphone X Thread 1: Signal sigabrt error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

It indicates that part of code

```
[AppDelegate _initialize];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

That is log :

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

How to solve it?

Comment: There should have before the stack trace, and a line saying `Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSUncaughtException` (note that the "Terminating" has an uppercase, an "NSException" is "NSUncaughtException"). Give us that full error message in console, not just the last line.

Comment: The pointer to UIApplicationMain is a red herring. You need to add an exception breakpoint and find out where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an exception breakpoint to see where the code is failing and gain some more insight as to why.

Do this in the breakpoint tab of Xcode. At the bottom is an add button (+).

Then, run your code again and get the crash to happen with the breakpoint active. This should now show you exactly the line where things are crashing, and more details about what’s going on when it happens.